# Ionic Scroll is leaving some extra width

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have a ion-scroll that shows a serie of products name, the problem is that when I scroll horizontally the scroll is longer that needed, I mean I can scroll until I can't see any product.

Below I left the code :

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" class="brand-bar-scroll">
    <div class="brand-bar-wrapper">
      <a class="btn cstm-btn brand-item" ng-repeat="brand in brands" ng-click="setBrand(brand)">{{brand.name}}</a>
    </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

How can I fix it? I should set the width properly.

Comment: You specifically said it worked... Then why did you ask us the question?

Comment: @Dsafds I hardcoded the width, there is not a solution for all cases, it was an example, not a solution. I edited in order to not confuse.